# HOGDescriptor with videos to recognize objects

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

Unfortunately I am both a python and a openCV beginner, so wish to excuse me if the question is stupid.

I am trying to use a `cv2.HOGDescriptor` to recognize objects in a video. I am concerned with a frame-by-frame recognition (i.e. no tracking or so).

---

Here is what I am doing:

1. I read the video (currently a `.mpg`) by using

   ```
   capture = cv.CreateFileCapture(video_path) #some path in which I have my video
   #capturing frames
   frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture) #returns cv2.cv.iplimage
   ```
2. In order to ultimately use the detector on the frames (which I would do by using

   ```
   found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride, padding, scale)
   ```

   ) I figured that I need to convert `frame` from `cv2.cv.iplimage` to `numpy.ndarray`
   which I did by

   ```
   tmp = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,3)
   cv.CvtColor(frame,tmp,cv.CV_BGR2RGB)

   ararr = np.asarray(cv.GetMat(tmp)).
   ```

Now I have the following error:

```
    found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(ararr, winStride, padding, scale)
 TypeError: a float is required
```

where

```
    winStride=(8,8)
    padding=(32,32)
    scale=1.05
```

I really can't understand which element is the real problem here. I.e. which number should be the float?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to perform that extra conversion yourself, that problem is related to the mixing of the new and old OpenCV bindings for Python. The other problem regarding `hog.detectMultiScale` is simply due to incorrect parameter ordering.

The second problem can be directly seen by checking `help(cv2.HOGDescriptor().detectMultiScale)`:

```
detectMultiScale(img[, hitThreshold[, winStride[, padding[, 
           scale[, finalThreshold[, useMeanshiftGrouping]]]]]])
```

as you can see, every parameter is optional but the first (the image). The ordering is also important, since you are effectively using `winStride` as the first, while it is expected to be the second, and so on. You can used named arguments to pass it. (All this has been observed in the earlier answer.)

The other problem is the code mix, here is a sample code that you should consider using:

```
import sys
import cv2

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
hogParams = {'winStride': (8, 8), 'padding': (32, 32), 'scale': 1.05}

video = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    result = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, **hogParams)
    print result
```

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the nice python lesson! I am quite confused on one more thing: why in the cv2 binding there is not a function to open a window? I.e. `cv2.NamedWindow` gives error to me while `cv.NamedWindow` does not. Is there a right way to open a window and using new bindings?

Comment: @Acorbe unfortunately many functions have been renamed, you are probably after `cv2.namedWindow` (the casing is different).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the C++ version of [HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/ocl/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#void%20ocl%3a%3aHOGDescriptor%3a%3adetectMultiScale%28const%20oclMat&%20img,%20vector%3CRect%3E&%20found_locations,%20double%20hit_threshold,%20Size%20win_stride,%20Size%20padding,%20double%20scale0,%20int%20group_threshold%29) shows a `hit_threshold` parameter (of type `double`) prior to the `win_stride` argument.  So it appears you are missing an argument to the function.  To accept the default argument for `win_stride`, you should pass your addition arguments used in your question as keywords.

Comment: thanks, it made my code run. Although, in the opencv sample `peopledetect.py` which I am considering as a reference the function call is `found, w = hog.detectMultiScale(img, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=1.05)`. That file runs on my machine. Any clue?

Comment: Just a guess here but in that example, you are passing those arguments as keywords, which allows the method to use the default for `hit_threshold`.  But in your example above, your are using positional arguments so it thinks your `winStride` is being passed as the `hit_threshold` argument.

Comment: Yep, your clue was right! you may want to include your last comment in your answer so to facilitate other users in finding the answer.

basically the problem was that I stopped passing arguments as keywords. Super noob of me. Thanks