# unable to adjust grouping settings in OpenCV's hog.detectMultiScale (python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to set the grouping settings in the `hog.detectMultiScale` method from the OpenCV2 library (version 2.4.9).

What happens is that the `group_threshold` and `groupThreshold` parameters
are both not recognized in the python binding:

```
TypeError: 'group_threshold' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

and

```
TypeError: 'groupThreshold' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to set this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_threshold` or `groupThreshold` does not exist in the Python wrapper of `hog.detectMultiScale`.  Unfortunately, there is no documentation to prove it (typical of OpenCV docs), but there is a related doc in the GPU version of the HOG Descriptor here - http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-detectmultiscale

However, there seems to be inconsistency with the Python wrapper.  If you type in `help(cv2.HOGDescriptor().detectMultiScale)` in the Python REPL, this is what we get:

```
detectMultiScale(...)
    detectMultiScale(img[, hitThreshold[, winStride[, padding[, scale[,
    finalThreshold[, useMeanshiftGrouping]]]]]]) -> foundLocations, foundWeights
```

If you compare the docs with the Python wrapper, we can clearly see that there are some input parameters are missing, as well as different parameters between them both.

As such, it doesn't look like you can vary this parameter :(.  Sorry if this isn't what you wanted to hear!  However, this StackOverflow post may prove to be insightful if you want to get it working relatively well:

[HOGDescriptor with videos to recognize objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400560/hogdescriptor-with-videos-to-recognize-objects)

---

Good luck!